# If the current flow the 'circular' wire, where is the potential difference?

Tags: electric-circuits

I learned that the current flow through the wire as there is a potential difference. If the wire is circular, the current can flow through the wire. But I think there is no potential difference.

Though there is no potential difference, how can the current flow through the wire?

Comment: How you produce current in a circular wire?, I can't understand how circular wire can flow current without an emf producing source!

Comment: Yes, I think so, but if I make the wire with superconduction, it is possible to flow the current through the wire without the emf producing source.

Comment: Superconduction?

Comment: If you want to ask a question about superconductors, you should include the word "superconductor" somewhere in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currents can arise from an "internal" source of the circuit, for example a potential difference as you would expect (like a battery in a circuit). If a closed circular wire/loop has a current flowing through it as you asked, the current is not caused by an internal source. Something from the outside must drive the current around the loop. Typically, this is the change in a magnetic field in the form of Faraday's law. This is for example described [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) and for the case of a loop [here](https://opentextbc.ca/physicstestbook2/chapter/faradays-law-of-induction-lenzs-law/). The change in magnetic flux causes what is called an electromotive force (emf) and is very similar to a potential difference because it causes current to flow. More generally I think you could say that the potential difference causes an electromotive force and the change of magnetic flux does as well. There might even be other causes of electromotive forces that I didn't think of right now that would also cause current to flow in your wire!